# How to reload page when inactive (no mouse movement, no keyboard press) including iframe Content

Tags: javascript, html

I have an iframe that needs to reload when inactive; however, using [this](http://jsfiddle.net/newdark/rGRA3/) link I found that with an iframe it does not work, meaning that if I type or mouseover in the iframe the page will not reload. I was hoping to be able to make this work.

```js
function keydown(evt) {
    if (!evt) evt = event;
    if (evt.keyCode == 192) {
        // Shift+TAB
        toggle_on_off();
    }
} // function keydown(evt)
 
//The full code can be found on JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/newdark/rGRA3/
```

Thank you!

Comment: Put the code inside the page that's loaded in the frame. Not the host page.

Comment: It's a google form, I don't have access/can't edit it

Comment: You could try the opposite. Run a function constantly that will reload the page every many milliseconds unless a key is pressed or the mouse is moved.